# Getting different answer when evaluating an integral from a released exam.

Tags: calculus

I am working on problem number 3a on [this exam](https://tbp.berkeley.edu/examfiles/math/math1A-fa97-final-Bergman-exam.pdf).

> Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $(0,+\infty)$, and $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers such that $f(ax)=bf(x)$ for all $x>0$.  Show that if $F$ is any antiderivative of $f$, there will exist a constant $k$ such that $F(ax)=abF(x)+k$ for all $x>0$.

My thought process was:

$$F(ax)=\int f(ax)\, dx=\int bf(x)\,dx=b\int f(x)\,dx=bF(x)+C$$

Change $C$ to $k$ to adapt to the question:

$$ = bF(x) + k $$

Also tried doing U-substitution:

$$F(ax)=\int f(u)\,du$$

where $u=ax$ and $du=a\,dx$

which gives:

$$\frac{1}{a}F(ax) + C$$

but my way of doing it doesn't have the $a$ in the end result. I feel like I'm probably forgetting some simple rule but I can't remember it. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're so close to having the answer!

You've calculated expressions for $F(ax)$ up to constants of integration in two ways, so the two expressions must differ by a constant (of integration). That is, there are constants $C_1, C_2$ such that
$$bF(x) + C_1 = \frac{1}{a}F(ax) + C_2$$
Now just multiply through by $a$ and rename your constants appropriately.

Comment: I'm glad it wasn't me forgetting a rule. I get it. Multiply by 1/a and k = aC1 - aC2. Thanks! Hahaha.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to add C to the second integration... darn it. XD

Comment: Multiply by a ... not 1/a

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to think about it, which is probably equivalent to your argument (completed by Clive):

We want to prove that there exists a constant $k$ such that $F(ax) = abF(x) + k$. Let $L(x) = F(ax)$ and $R(x) = abF(x)$ ($L$ and $R$ for left and right, respectively). Then $L'(x) = R'(x) = abf(x)$. Since $L$ and $R$ have the same derivative, they must differ by a constant.